# Using DirectShow to capture frames and OpenCV to Process

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, video-streaming, directshow

I have made two different solutions for Video-to-Image Capturing and was wondering if I could intertwine the best of both worlds.  I am currently using DirectShow to load in an AVI file and capture images.  However, DirectShow's lack of image processing capabilities and the need to make additional filters have stopped me dead in my tracks.

I then turned to OpenCV.

It has all the image processing functions I need, but it has trouble loading in the videos that the DirectShow solution was able to retrieve.  Are there any tutorials online about this process or anything close to it?  Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, here is a link to an article: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/DirectShow

Comment: While it showed the theory behind what was needed to be done I understood the concept and filled in the blanks. Thank you for that link. All I'm going to add is that the cvConvertImage function will error out with just a BYTE buffer. I had to take my create IplImage variable and have its imageData point to the buffer and it's origin point to the data. Ex. cvImage->imageData = dsImage; cvImage->imageDataOrigin = cvImage->imageData;

Comment: This link is broken now.

Comment: @Aposhian it sure has and that was a long time ago ;) Hopefully this helps you I found on a google search https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html