# How to use OpenCV with DirectShow

Tags: image-processing, opencv, directshow, video-processing

DirectShow has great capturing and rendering abilities but no image processing capability. I found an [article](http://www.laganiere.name/directshowTut/section3.shtml) on how to use opencv with directshow. It is probably old. I could not find Proxytrans filter in my OpenCV 2.3.1. Is there an alternative to this?

Comment: Check this out:

 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018092/using-directshow-to-capture-frames-and-opencv-to-process

Comment: I am sorry but the link you gave finally points to the link in my question. Any other solution?

Comment: At the very least you can use DirectShow's 'Sample Grabber Filter' to capture you the streamed data via its `SampleCB` callback. Within the handler, you can use OpenCV classes to wrap the payload buffer and use it with OpenCV functions. This does not require anything within OpenCV, however the latter might go one step further and provide an additional helper filter.

Comment: The Sample grabber filter is a part of DitrectShow editing Services which is not a part of the latest Windows SDK. Any other solutions?

Comment: Sample Grabber is available in all base versions of Windows since at least Win 2K. It is marked deprecated but is unlikely to be ever removed.